# Finding closest integer from an array which is rounded up

Tags: java

I'm not good at english so title can be confusing.

**What i'm trying to do:**

I have a int array `10, 20, 30` and I want to take numbers from it based on `number` variable

if `int number = 10;`

I want the result from the "method" to be `20`

if `int number = 21;`

i want the result to be `30`

I don't know how to explain this properly, but I hope it's understandable.

---

What is this for? I have a player inventory which can has different sizes `9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54` and I have a item contents which is for example `5`. So I want to have inventory size `9`. If the item content size was `19`, inventory size should be `27`, not `18`. And that's my problem.

---

I tried a lot of different iterations, calculations but every attempt was very unsuccesful. 
I had this method to get a closest value from an array, but i don't know how to change it to round up.

```
public int getClosestInteger(int value, int[] numbers) {
        int distance = Math.abs(numbers[0] - value);
        int id = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
            int dist = Math.abs(numbers[i] - value);

            if(dist < distance){
                id = i; distance = dist;
            }
        }
        return numbers[id];
    }
```

**How I can do that?**

Comment: `If the item content size was 19, inventory size should be 27, not 18. And that's my problem.` ... your explained logic makes no sense then, because `19` should be treated as `20`, which is closer to `18` than `27`.  You need to  clearly articulate your logic if you want an answer.

Comment: It makes sense. If the items size is `19` - i want to have **bigger** inventory size, which in this case is `27`. I can't have `inventory size = 20` because of game that i'm modding. It must be `9, 18...` ;p

And having inventory size equal to `18` when te item size are `19` isn't a good idea. One item would disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
public int getClosestInteger(int value, int[] numbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if(value < numbers[i]){
            return numbers[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the array `numbers` is sorted in ascending order.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen A simple Arrays.sort(numbers) would do the rest, but it looks like a sorted array in his question.

Answer (score 0):

it should work.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if(numbers[i] > value){
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
```